# Tabhost- set the badge position in tabs Android

Tags: android, tabs, notifications, android-view, tabwidget

I am new to badge's concept. In my application i want to show the badges on one tab. For that i used the android-viewbadger.jar file [Android ViewBadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)
it is working fine with 4 tabs,

```
    TabWidget tabs = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
    badge1 = new BadgeView(this, tabs, 1);
    badge1.setText("155");
    badge1.setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    badge1.toggle();
```

[image]

when i add one more tab here it will look like this

[image]

i have already use these badge properties

```
    badge1.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
    badge1.setTextSize(15);
    badge1.setBadgeMargin(5,5);
    badge1.setWidth(10);
```

Comment: http://kevinpelgrims.com/blog/2014/06/24/adding-a-badge-to-an-actionbar-tab

Answer (score 1):

Setting badge on TabWidget will only show the badge in the space available between the drawable and the boundary of TabWidget, so adding more tabs will compress the badge. Instead using setIndicator(String,Drawable), try this:

```
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.whoseinterested);
    whosespec.setIndicator(iv);
    Intent whoseIntent = new Intent(this, BlankActivity.class);
    whosespec.setContent(whoseIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(whosespec);

    badge1 = new BadgeView(this, iv);
    badge1.setText("155");
    badge1.setTextSize(15);
    badge1.setBadgeBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    badge1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    badge1.toggle();
```

Screenshot:
[image: screen]

You can clearly see in your screenshot that the image in the tab with badge is shifted towards the center. If there is no space between image and its tab boundary, it will not be displayed properly.

**Source :** Tested myself.

Comment: this is perfectly answer and work like a charm @berserk thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

Hi  set badge in child of view of tab   in imageview

try this

```
    TabWidget tabsw = (TabWidget) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
        ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) tabsw.getChildAt(0);
        viewgroup.getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < viewgroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (viewgroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageView) {
                ImageView new_name = (ImageView) viewgroup.getChildAt(i);
                badge7 = new BadgeView(getActivity(),new_name);
                badge7.setText("9");
                badge7.setTextSize(9);
                badge7.setBadgeMargin(0,0);
                badge7.setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT);
                badge7.toggle();

            }
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402748/tabhost-android-viewbadger-badge-issue
have a look at this question @calinbros